# Keep companion property from the child class but not from the parent

Tags: kotlin, proguard, obfuscation, companion-object

My situation is the following

I have class with a public companion object as it follows:

```kotlin
open class ParentClass {
...
   companion object {
      ...
      const val CONST_PROPERTY = "value"
   }
}
```

And other class `ChildClassFromParentClass` which inherits from `ParentClass`.

I use this property like this:

```kotlin
import package.ChildClassFromParentClass

class OtherClass {

...
   private fun doStuff() {
     val variable = ChildClassFromParentClass.CONST_PROPERTY
   }
...
}
```

It is possible to configure `proguard-rules.pro` to expose `ChildClassFromParentClass.CONST_PROPERTY` but obfuscate `ParentClass.CONST_PROPERTY`?

I've tried this, but it's not working

```kotlin
-keepclassmembers class package.ChildClassFromParentClass$** {
    public static ** Companion;
}
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what do you mean. You can't access `ParentClass.CONST_PROPERTY` using `ChildClassFromParentClass.CONST_PROPERTY` as you show in your example.

Comment: I can. ChildClassFromParentClass inherits from ParentClass and CONST_PROPERTY is public

Comment: Please provide a full example, as what you say doesn't really seem correct: https://pl.kotl.in/sEp-vCgO-